# Not getting any results back from a raw query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a raw query and when I run this query in phpMyAdmin it returns 3 results but when I try to use Laravel Query Builder I get an empty array.

My query

```
SELECT id, reply_text, sending_time
FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
WHERE phone_number
IN ('+1234567819',  '+19873216154',  '+15984989898')
AND id IN (
    SELECT MAX( id ) 
    FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
    GROUP BY phone_number
)
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
| id |   reply_text    |    sending_time     |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
| 87 | This is a test  | 2019-07-30 08:25:26 |
| 54 | And another one | 2019-07-29 06:35:11 |
| 12 | Last test       | 2019-06-16 09:44:26 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
```

But when I try to do this query with Laravel I get back an empty array []

```
dump($phone_numbers);

// 0 => "+1234567819"
// 1 => "+19873216154"
// 2 => "+15984989898"

$phone_numbers = implode("','", $phone_numbers);
dump($phone_numbers);


// +1234567819','+19873216154','+15984989898


dump("SELECT id, reply_text, sending_time
                  FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
                  WHERE phone_number IN ('$phone_numbers')
                  AND id IN (
                      SELECT MAX(id)
                      FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
                      GROUP BY phone_number
                  )");


// SELECT id, reply_text, sending_time
// FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
// WHERE phone_number
// IN ('+1234567819',  '+19873216154',  '+15984989898')
// AND id IN (
//  SELECT MAX( id ) 
//  FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
//  GROUP BY phone_number
// )



$replies = DB::connection('second_connection')
             ->select("
                  SELECT id, reply_text, sending_time
                  FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
                  WHERE phone_number IN (':phone_numbers')
                  AND id IN (
                      SELECT MAX(id)
                      FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
                      GROUP BY phone_number
                  )
             ", ['phone_numbers' => $phone_numbers]);

dump($replies);

// []
```

*P.S. Here is the output of the Query Log*

I can't understand why it is returning an empty array. But when I run the raw query in phpMyAdmin it returns results so I know that the query is correct.

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [query] => 
          SELECT id, reply_text, sending_time
          FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
          WHERE phone_number IN (':phone_numbers')
          AND id IN (
              SELECT MAX(id)
              FROM sms_sender_inbox_replies
              GROUP BY phone_number
          )

      [bindings] => Array
          (
              [phone_numbers] => +1234567819','+19873216154','+15984989898
          )

        [time] => 0.7
    )
)
```

Comment: first you should use `selectRaw()` or `select(DB::raw(` second you forgot to get the result of the query with `get()`. Here you can find the docs on query builder: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: @dparoli Calling `select` directly off the `connection` is  not the same as `select` on the query builder. Essentially, you do use a raw query and you don't use `->get()`

Comment: @Rwd, my fault, it's the first time I saw it used for raw query, I don't remember if there is an example of this kind of in the docs.

Comment: No you do have to use get(), the missing `get()` is responsible for nearly 80% of the laravel query issues here on S.O.

Comment: @dparoli `DB::select()` or `DB::connection(...)->select()` is a method on the `Connection` class. `DB::from()->select()` is a method on the `Builder` class. You do have to use `get()` with the `Builder` but not on the `Connection`. Chaining on `get()` to the connection select with result in `Call to a member function get() on array`.

Comment: @Rwd very clear, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you bind it like that, you try to find the `phone_number` `IN` as a single value (not as 3 values). A placeholder can only be to a single value, not to an array - but you can work around this using the QueryBuilder methods, which simplifies bindings.

```
$phone_numbers = ["+1234567819", "+19873216154", "+15984989898"];

$result = DB::connection('second_connection')
            ->table('sms_sender_inbox_replies')
            ->select('id', 'reply_text', 'sending_time')
            ->whereIn('phone_number', $phone_numbers)
            ->whereIn('id', DB::table('sms_sender_inbox_replies')
                              ->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
                              ->groupBy('phone_number')
                              ->get())
            ->get();
```

Comment: Getting this "message": "Call to a member function groupBy() on integer"

Comment: Might need it the other way around - give it a try. Otherwise we can do `selectRaw("MAX(id)")` before the `groupBy` and remove the `max('id')` method.

Comment: Now I'm getting "message": "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, integer given